# How to resize JFrame and show JPanel and/or its controls with a button?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have made simple form that looks like this:

[image]

How to make the Show Details button display an additional panel and form like this:

[image]

And when the button is clicked again, it hides the control and the panel.

Comment: Well that´s not too hard to do. There are about a hundreth questions and answer about resizing a JFrame on this site. You will probably need to reload your LayoutManager so it can adapt to the new size but other than that it should work perfectly fine. Although the more elegant way would be to minimize the table and use that gained space for your details.

Comment: How did you create your simple form? How did you create your expanded form?

Comment: @matt its just the sample, i add the controls manualy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After display / hide the details panel, `pack()` must be called to resize the frame. And `setLocationRelativeTo()` respectively to position itself correctly.

Here is an example

**Main.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame("Test Frame").setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private DetailsPanel detailsPanel;

    public MainFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        detailsPanel = new DetailsPanel();

        add(new MainPanel(this), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void showDetails(boolean show) {
        detailsPanel.setVisible(show);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

**MainPanel.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private MainFrame owner;
    private JButton showDetailsButton;

    private boolean details = false;

    public MainPanel(MainFrame owner) {
        super();
        this.owner = owner;

        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        showDetailsButton = new JButton("Details >>>");
        showDetailsButton.addActionListener(this::showDetais);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        buttonsPanel.add(showDetailsButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());


        add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void showDetais(ActionEvent event) {
        showDetailsButton.setText(details ? "Details >>>" : "<<< Details");

        details = !details;
        owner.showDetails(details);
    }
}
```

and **DetailsPanel.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {

    public DetailsPanel() {
        super();
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 800));
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: using this.pack() and toggling panel visibility solve my problem. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the controls from `Filter` down through `Show Details` are in a single (permanently viewable - PV) panel, and the controls to be show/hidden are in a second (hide or show - HS `hideOrShowPanel`) panel. Put the PV panel in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout` and the HS panel in the `LINE_END`.

On button toggle, call..

```
private void changePanelVisibility(Boolean visible) {
    hideOrShowPanel.setVisible(visible);
    topLevelContainer.pack(); // revalidate layout and size the GUI to fit the controls
}
```

The `topLevelContainer` might be a `JFrame`, but this GUI seems better suited to being displayed in a `JDialog`. Especially so since this would look best in a fixed size (non user resizable) top level container, which the dialog is by default.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend a bit on the LayoutManager that you use. But in general, have the Details-panel always added to the Dialog, but set it invisible at start. When pressing the "Show Details" button, toggle the visibility of the Details panel and resize the dialog to accommodate for the additional space it requires.